# Cross application authentication IIS to sub application

Tags: .net, iis, forms-authentication, cross-application

The issue I am having is I get a second login request when directed to the page in FileUploadWAP application.  If the login code and config are deployed to the root default site the shared authentication works.  I suspect that the path to the cookie is the problem or the machineKey.

Web site in IIS
DefaultWebSite
    Other Application1
    Other Application2
    StaffLocal  (is an application)
        FileUploadWAP  (is an application under StaffLocal )

```
Web Config file in StaffLocal  
<authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" 
         name="StaffWeb"
         timeout="610" 
         path="/" 
         slidingExpiration="true"
         enableCrossAppRedirects="true" 
         protection="All">
        </forms>        
</authentication>

Web Config file in StaffLocal/FileUploadWAP  
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="../Login.aspx" (If the .. are removed get error can’t find Login.aspx.)
    name="StaffWeb"
    timeout="610" 
    path="../"     (have tried / and ../ and other variants)
    slidingExpiration="true" 
    enableCrossAppRedirects="true"
    protection="All">
    </forms>
</authentication>

Same in both configs
<machineKey 
    decryption="DES" 
    decryptionKey="966CF55FB064D15A13789E90CF5B91E640436E07AB6C71A3" 
    validation="SHA1"
```

validationKey="E329E5ECDD7EE4B3BDF27A563F91A38888FA95E5259914DBADD86F9ED681A41732E609F8338" />

Comment: Web site in IIS  DefaultWebSite Other Application1 Other Application2 StaffLocal (is an application) FileUploadWAP (is an application under StaffLocal )

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.  I changed the configs to use AES and authentication started working.